# Remove files and support import for the files

Tags: python, python-import

I'm working on a python project that has some of duplicated code.

I'm trying to remove the duplicated files, and keep only one file, however, my problem is that others projects already use the removes files, and I don't want to have to change their imports.

Example:

`src/
-----a.py
-----b.py`

Lets assume both `a` and `b` implement the same function `f`, and there are pieces of code in the other project who uses `from src.a import f` and others use `from src.b import f`

Right now my solution is to keep the implementation in `a` and have `b` only contain `from src.a import f`.

Is there a different way where I could completely remove `b` but still have the ability to use `from src.b import f` ?

Comment: By not refactoring your code you are creating additional technological debt. This is almost always wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a horrible import hook hack that emulates a virtual `b.py`, no.

However, you can just make `b.py` a "re-export" module like

```py
from a import foo, baz, quux
```

assuming those are the duplicate names.

Comment: Appriciate the quick answer. Currently, this is the solution I'm using, but I'm looking specifically for a 'horrible import hook hack'. I came across sys.meta_path hacking but from my understanding it should not work after python 3.3.

Comment: Maybe look into synthesizing something into `sys.modules` if you're really sure. I really would not recommend that.